# ViewPager should'n scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I'm testing the tutorial on http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/ and it works really well, but I've got a little problem.

If my image is zoomed, I don't want to swipe between the pages until I reach the edge of my image. How could I check it with the tutorial code?

I know, that I have to override onInterceptTouchEvent in a custom ViewPager and return false. But how can I check, if I should return true or false?

Edit: My image is zoomed by changing matrix-values.

Comment: For this you need to take TouchImageView which extend ImageView..

Comment: And what have I to change/add in this file?

Comment: Follow this library..https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Hmm, I watched to library, but it a different concept of zooming the images. My image is zoomed be changing the matrix-values. The 6th value is the pos.x and if this is zero, I know, I'm on the most left. But how to figure out, that I'm at the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a custom ImageView with custom ViewPager, in ImageView, override onMeasure, onTouchEvent, for details check this library: https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery